# changing dynamically created button size on rotation

Tags: ios, properties, uibutton

I have created this button dynamically. It will be created and populated with data from our database, so I cannot use IB. However, in IB you can declare a @property and do things to later (like resize and position on rotation). My Question is; how do give properties to dynamically created buttons so I can change the size when I rotate to landscape using UIInterfaceOrientation theOrientation = = self.interfaceOrientation;?

```
        UIButton *buttonWineries = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,yPositionWineries, 300, 160)];
        buttonWineries.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
        buttonWineries.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        buttonWineries.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        [buttonWineries setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [self.wineriesMenu addSubview:buttonWineries];
        yPositionWineries += 190;
        [buttonWineries addTarget:self action:@selector(btnWineryDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359364/how-to-creating-dynamic-buttons-iphone-xcode

Comment: thanks but there are 3 answers. not sure which one to look at.

Comment: Using the superview with tag. The link to docs is a very useful source as well.

Comment: Ok. i will try to figure that out. Because I am returning a ton of data from the database and I need to style it. It all works great in portrait, I can style and place things in the loop, but since the styling is happening in a different place than the rotation, I am stuck with repositioning things and a few style elements in the rotation. This is also happening with dynamically created labels and text views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a better solution for it . Just do one thing that in your .h file implement this line

```
@interface yourViewController:UIViewController 
{
   UIButton *buttonWineries;
}
```

and implement this code into .m file

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

   buttonWineries = [[UIButton alloc]init];
   buttonWineries.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
   buttonWineries.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
   buttonWineries.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
   [buttonWineries setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
   [self.wineriesMenu addSubview:buttonWineries];
   yPositionWineries += 190;
   [buttonWineries addTarget:self action:@selector(btnWineryDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

   BOOL isPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);
   // now do whatever you need

   if(isPortrait)
     [buttonWineriessetFrame:CGRectMake(10,yPositionWineries, 300, 160)];
   else
     [buttonWineriessetFrame:CGRectMake(//your frame size for lanscape)];

}


// check your orientation angel and change your button size inside this delegate method

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
     // Return YES for supported orientations
     if (willRotateToInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
         if (buttonWineries) 
            [buttonWineries setFrame:CGRectMake(//put your frame size here)];
     }
     if (willRotateToInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
          if (buttonWineries)   
            [buttonWineries setFrame:CGRectMake(//put your frame size here)];

     }
}
```

**OR**

you can add didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation in place of willRotateToInterfaceOrientation to stop animation while resize or position  change

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
     // Return YES for supported orientations
     if (willRotateToInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
         if (buttonWineries) 
            [buttonWineries setFrame:CGRectMake(//put your frame size here)];
     }
     if (willRotateToInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
          if (buttonWineries)   
            [buttonWineries setFrame:CGRectMake(//put your frame size here)];

     }
    if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
          if (buttonWineries)  
             [buttonWineries setFrame:CGRectMake(//put your frame size here)];
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you . Please let me know if you still facing any problem . Thanks

Comment: Won't it be better if you use        willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration instead of the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:? This way resizing your button will be animated, making user experience better.

Comment: Almost. But I need to keep the button inside my for loop. Putting it in the viewDidLoad only created one button. It does change when I rotate it. But when I put it back inside the for loop, nothing happens. Perhaps I should have mentioned that it is inside of a for loop: -(void)putWineriesButtonsInScrollView:(int)numberOfButtons{
   for (int i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++)...{ (array, myButton, labels here)... then add the scrollView  }
    
    [self.wineriesMenu setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.wineriesMenu.frame.size.width, yPositionWineries)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.wineriesMenu];
}

Comment: It depend on situation whatever you want . I needed animation so i have implemented it with willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration. If any body don't need any animation he/she can use didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method for it

Comment: hi  user1510450, ok for it you just check it your button is exist or not inside your viewcontroller then set any frame size to it. Please have a look on my updated code

Comment: This is working now when I rotate. Problem: if I put the button code either in viewDidLoad OR in my for loop, it wants to load the portrait view first because we created the button in portrait view. So if I enter the page in landscape, it loads the portrait view, then I have to rotate for it to start receiving messages from the rotation method.

Comment: hi chandan. Is there a way to make the button without actual dimensions and tell it to look at the rotation for its dimensions so it loads portrait or landscape respectively?

Comment: hi user1510450.  for it you can check orientation via this code    

BOOL isPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);  and //create your button according to isPortrait flag. Please have a luk my updated answer

Comment: Please have a look on my updated code and let me know if still you are facing this problem.

Comment: Kool. Your updated code seems to work. Thanks. Will post again if any problems.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Please vote up it if you really want to appreciate this answer and me too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just set the frame.

```
buttonWineries.frame = CGRectMake(...);
```

Comment: I did, and get that trusty old message "use of undeclared identifier"

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `@property` to declare properties for dynamically-created views, using the same syntax you're familiar with (though you can drop the `IBOutlet` if you want). To connect the property to the button, instead of doing this:

```
UIButton *buttonWineries = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,yPositionWineries, 300, 160)];
```

Just do this:

```
self.buttonWineries = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,yPositionWineries, 300, 160)];
```

Access the button using `self.buttonWineries`, the same way you would if it were an Interface Builder outlet.

If you're actually creating several different buttons, you may want to make the `@property` be an `NSMutableArray` instead of a `UIButton`. Use `-addObject:` to add each button to the array.